# Why uploading private files to a public folder is dangerous? - I need to understand the risks please

Tags: security

I currently use Laravel to upload admin only files to a private folder. The folder is not accessible directly from the web as it resides below the root and only logged-in users with the correct role can access them. All good.

I have see a lot of devs creating folders here:
`public_html/private_folder/image.jpg`

And only drop an empty index.html file inside the `public_html/private_folder/`

If the image file name is encoded like this:
`public_html/private_folder/9879879gfd9gdf987d9fg87.jpg`

How can hacker access all the files in that directory from the web without uploading an infected script to the server?

I tried to test a folder from a dev I work with(who had this security issue) and could not manage to guess the file names in that directory(even using many scanners). I could only access them publicly when I knew in advance the direction and file name.

Any idea please? As I would like to understand why I have always learned it the Laravel way (so I can explain it to other devs). Because telling them to change their scripts inner working without being able to explain why and demo the security issue live in front of their eyes is a bit frustrating for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what the developers are doing might be acceptable in some circumstances, but they need to understand the big picture. It goes like this:

- Files located under `public_html/private_folder/9879879gfd9gdf987d9fg87.jpg` are protected by the secret in the file name. The protection is as strong as the entropy of the file name (here about 60 bits; counted by my keepass) which is not enough from the modern crypto perspective (at least 128 is advised).
- This solution is highly sensitive to server misconfigurations. It might be easy to expose the files due to mistakenly allowing directory listings. Cooperation with the server admin is needed.
- What will happen, if you - instead of pasting the URL into the browsers URL field - paste it into google? You literally send the secret to google. Will you rotate the file name? You should, as the secret has been shared with a third party. In a moment it might be scraped by a crawler and ceases to be a secret in the first place.
- Actually because of what has been stated above people should only share their own files this way and be personally responsible for their secrecy. I would disallow doing it for corporate data where the user does not feel this responsibility and might share the links by putting them into word documents, excel files, remote drives and so on.

Comment: One way that "secret" URLs like this often get leaked is when *they contain* links to another place and that other place somehow reveals its referrer logs in some way (which is not usually a security issue for *them*, but can make *your secret URL* public knowledge). That doesn't apply to JPEG images directly, of course, but can easily happen with HTML files.

Comment: Thank you very much for both your replies, so there is no way for a hacker to scan the server for the main folder and find these files? No tools available out there which would brute force the names? Because the pasting of URLS, will not happen as the files are uploaded and only pass as downloads in the admin panel.

Comment: There are tools to brute force (Burp, OWASP ZAP, ...) and it is easy to use them. That's why you need to have sufficient entropy to protect the files (and 128 bits should do the job just fine). Given you don't have any server misconfigurations (or simply do something stupid), this approach should be ok from the security perspective.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check online for such tools, as I need to understand more about hacking in order to build better applications.